# Doubts in $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{A^k(z)}{k}=\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-A(z)}\right) $

Tags: definite-integrals, generating-functions, analytic-combinatorics

I'm trying to prove that $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{A^k(z)}{k}=\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-A(z)}\right)$,  (for those who know about the topic of analytical combinatorics, you may notice that it is the generating function of Cyc$(\mathcal{A})$). My proof attempt is the following:

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{A^k(z)}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^{k+1}(z)}{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{A(z)} x^k\;\text{d}x=\int_0^{A(z)} \frac{\text{d}x}{1-x}=-\ln(1-A(z))=\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-A(z)}\right)$, where $A(z)$ is an exponential generating function associated with class $\mathcal{A}$.

It seems to me that the attempted proof is not bad, but my professor made an observation to me regarding $A(z)$ as the limit of integration. "Is $A(z)$ a number, or a function? And if it were a function, what sense would the integral have?" I honestly did not understand the meaning of the question, I consider that the integration limit should be considered as the generating function, but now I am a little doubtful.

And I would like to know where exactly my teacher's question is going, is there something that I am not understanding about equality or is there something that he is not understanding? I'm confused

Comment: If this problem is from combinatorics, it is possible that the identity is intended as an equality between formal power series. If this is the case, then integration doesn't make sense. On the other hand, if the identity is intended as an equality between analytic functions, then invoking calculus is sort of okay here but we have to be careful in conjunction with all that pesky issue of branch cut of the complex logarithm.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you, those are the details that I still have trouble seeing, but why does the meaning change depending on the context? If you like, you could explain the comment better in the form of an answer to mark it as correct.

Comment: If you can argue that $|A(z) |<1$ then just substitute $x=A(z)$ into the standard Maclaurin series of $-\log(1-x) $.

Comment: The answer to this question really depends on what $A(z)$ is. Is $A(z)$ a formal power series, an analytic function (over some domain), something entirely different? What precisely is $A(z)$?

Comment: @C-RAM $A(z)$ is a generating function (formal power series)

Comment: I see; then as Sangchul Lee's comment suggests, this identity should problably be regarded as an equality between formal power series (and unfortunately, I don't think Gary's hint makes much sense in that context). I think this particular confusion may stem from a broader confusion about what a formal power series actually is (I see you've asked a few questions on the subject already). In short, the bounds of an integral must be numbers (real or complex depending on context), and $A(z)$ is simply not a number.

Comment: Although, I myself have some confusion about what's being asked here (which is why I haven't answered). Keep in mind, I haven't read *Analytic Combinatorics* in particular, or taken your specific class, so this may be a product of the specific way in which your prof or the book defines and treats FPS, but under the treatment I'm familiar with, the identity you're being asked to prove (if indeed it is an equality of FPS) is simply an instance of the definition of FPS composition rather than a theorem that needs to be proven. How has your class defined the composition of FPS given by $B(A(z))$?

Comment: @C-RAM if $A(x)$ be the generating function for $a_n, a_0=0$, and $B(x)$ be the generating function for $b_n$, then $B(A(x))=\sum a_n A(x)^n$

Comment: Ok, so my question is: assuming $$\ln\left(\frac1{1-z}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}k$$ by definition, isn't the identity $$\ln\left(\frac1{1-A(z)}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{A(z)^k}k$$ immediate from the definition of FPS composition? What is there to prove?